# To split the string values stored in array

Tags: python, string, numpy, lambda, split

```
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

a=np.array(['ma_ya','dj_kh','ja_aa'])

a1=(lambda x:x[0].split('_'),a)
a1
```

output:

```
 (<function __main__.<lambda>>, array(['ma_ya', 'dj_kh', 'ja_aa'], 
       dtype='<U5'))
```

i want the output to be `['ma','dj','ja']` using lambda function. kindly help

Comment: Does it need to use numpy for some reason? Otherwise `a1 = map(lambda x: x.split('_')[0] , a)` should work

Answer (score 1):

```
a1 = list(map(lambda x: x.split('_')[0], a))
```

Answer (score 1):

As `a` is a `np.array`, you can use list comprehension

```py
a1 = [x.split('_')[0] for x in a]
```

Outputs:
`['ma', 'dj', 'ja']`

Answer (score 0):

```
a1 = list(map(lambda x: x.split("_")[0], a))

print(a1)
```

### Output:

```
['ma', 'dj', 'ja']
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, use `pd.Series`:

```
a1=pd.Series(a).apply(lambda x:x.split('_')[0])
```

result:

```
0    ma
1    dj
2    ja
dtype: object
```

or convert to list:

```
a1=list(pd.Series(a).apply(lambda x:x.split('_')[0]))
```

output:

```
['ma', 'dj', 'ja']
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use list comprehension instead of using lambda as shown here

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
a=np.array(['ma_ya','dj_kh','ja_aa'])
a1=[i.split('_')[0] for i in a]
print(a1)
```

Output :
['ma', 'dj', 'ja']

Comment: How is this different to [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62691429/13676202)?. This actually borders plagiarism.

Comment: I was writing this answer and till then the same answer was already posted.I didn't check then.

Comment: Yes, that's true, it usually happens, but now that you realize that the answer had already been published, the best thing would be to edit it to give a different answer or delete it, otherwise it could be considered plagiarism.

Answer (score 0):

Using `list-comprehension`:

```
s = ['ma_ya','dj_kh','ja_aa']

print([x.split('_')[0] for x in s])
```

OUTPUT:

```
['ma','dj','ja']
```

Comment: How is this different to [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62691429/13676202)?. This actually borders plagiarism.